# Creating Glyph Icons, icons not showing up

Tags: html, css, svg

So I'm working on creating a glyphicon library for a future set of projects. I believe I have set up the icon set correctly, with the CSS, but it's not showing up for some reason.

**svg file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<metadata></metadata>
<defs>
<glyph unicode="&#xf000;" d='M3,18H13V16H3Zm0-5H21V11H3ZM3,6V8H17V6Z'/>
</font>
</defs></svg>
```

**css file**

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'SupportWorks';
    src: url('../font/sw-icon-proto.svg#supportworksicons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sw {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 SupportWorks;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes sw-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes sw-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.sw-menu:before{
    content: "\f000";
}
```

I have found that the icons are stored in a compressed format inside a single svg file, and brought out via Unicode inside a CSS doc.

Comment: Suggestion would be to check the icon path in the rendered HTML of the browser.

Comment: Since you are including the SVG via the CSS file, the path needs to be relative to the CSS file, not the page that's including the CSS.

Comment: @hungerstar can you show me an example of what you are talking about? I guess I'm not reading your statement correctly.

Comment: @HameedSyed Icon path seems to be fine.

Comment: Browsers don't support gyphs. How are you testing this. Normally this would be processed into something a browser would support.

Comment: There's no opening `<font>` tag? Also, a `<font-face>` element may be necessary.

Comment: @RobertLongson so I need to turn it into a ttf then?

Comment: @Ouroborus there needs to be those tags?

Comment: @MarkHill The document is malformed if the elements do not have both opening and closing elements or are self-closing. You only have the closing `</font>` tag. As for `<font-face>`, I don't know if it's optional or not. See the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html). Additionally, few browsers [support SVG webfonts](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts).